# sql backup file and filegroups options disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to set the backups for a specific filegroup on a database but the filegroup option is greyed out. It's available on the system databases and I created a new database to test and the test database is not greyed out.

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible cause: your database is set to simple recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database is in Simple Mode Recovery. To change it to Full:
Right Click On Database Name > Properties > Options tab >Recovery Model comboBox > Full